# Multiple threaded socket server in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I recently tried creating a socket server which can connect to multiple clients... I was too lazy to write a separate program for the client so I'm just using telnet.

The first time I connect(using telnet), it works fine... but the second telnet connection just hangs and the cmd screen goes blank...
Even the first connection gets hanged after sending a string.

Any help is appreciated

Here's the code:

[Chatserver.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imH6C.png)

I would really appreciate I if someone would correct the mistakes in the code and post it

You could have a look at it if you want but it might be easier if you just clicked the hyperlink and viewed the image:

```
package chatserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class Chat extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Chat server = new Chat();
        try {
            server.SERVER();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Chat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void SERVER() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(8068);
        Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
        InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
        PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());

        PS.println("What is your name: ");
        String name = BR.readLine();
        String Message = BR.readLine();
        PS.println(name + " : " + Message);
    }
}

public class ChatServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chat c1 = new Chat();
        Chat c2 = new Chat();
        while (true) {
            c1.start();
            c2.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Guys,
     Today I typed up the same code in python as I am much more familiar with it than I am with Java

I have succeeded in connecting to multiple clients but am unable to see outputs from chat() yet...
I would like to know what mistake I made in this code below and would be very grateful if someone helps me transcribe it to Java:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import threading
import time

clients = []
addr = []

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8068
client_no = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')

def connect(clnt_no):
    while True:
        s.listen(1)
        print('searching for clients')
        clnt, adr = s.accept()
        clients.append(clnt)
        addr.append(adr) 
        print('connected to: ',addr[clnt_no])
#       print(len(clients))
        clnt_no += 1
        client_no = clnt_no

def chat():
    while True:
        for x in range(0, client_no):
            data = clients[x] = recv(1204)
            if data:
                for y in range(0, client_no):
                    clients[y].send('from client ', x, ' ', data)
            else:
                print('no data recieved from any client')
def Main():
    conn = threading.Thread(target=connect, args=[0])
    cht = threading.Thread(target=chat) 
#   while True:
    conn.start()
    cht.start()     


if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    Main()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste the code into the question.  And how isn't it working?

Comment: Post the relevant code here directly, and you need to actually explain your problem. "But it's not working..." is extremely unhelpful.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I edited the question as you asked

Comment: @Deepesh Thanks. When you ask questions here, *never* post code as an image. That forces people to retype your code if they want to test it. Post it as text here from the start next time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate can you diagnose my code now? please

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

First, every instance of `Chat` is listening on port 8068.  You can only have one ServerSocket listening on a particular port, though it is free to `accept()` multiple connections.  If you paid attention to the exceptions you’re getting instead of ignoring them, you would see an exception informing you of this.

Second, since the `start()` method of Thread returns immediately rather than waiting for the thread to finish, your `while` loop is creating hundreds, if not thousands, of threads.  The only reason your system isn’t overwhelmed by them is because, as I mentioned above, all but the very first instance are immediately failing to bind their ServerSockets, so they return fairly quickly.

In summary, you need to create *one* server, with *one* ServerSocket.  You will need to call `accept()` inside a loop, but you must not create more than one ServerSocket.

Comment: so in chat applications like hangouts, messenger or WhatsApp, do they use multiple port addresses? .... I am new to this kind of stuff and I would request you to explain it in terms python as I am much more familiar with that and will be able to understand it better                                                  Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: No; as VGR says, one server socket can handle multiple connections.

Comment: @VGR How do I run  'Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();' in a loop, I need to assign different variables for each time right?